# How do i bold a text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to change text to bold, which is really hard.
I tried many times using various ways,
for example:

```
//1: 

document.getElementById('boldtext').innerHTML = "<b>" += document.getElementById('boldtext').innerHTML += "</b>"; //which dosent work

//2:

document.getElementById('boldtext').bold(); //dosent work too
```

Any ideas on how to **bold** text in Javascript?

```
//My code so far:
The whole code is this: function getSelectionText() { var text = ""; if (window.getSelection) { text = window.getSelection().toString(); } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") { text = document.selection.createRange().text; } alert(text); }; let BoldButton = document.createElement('input'); /*boldbuttonlol*/ BoldButton.type = 'button'; BoldButton.value = 'bold highlighted text'; BoldButton.onclick = () => { getSelectionText(); }; document.body.appendChild(BoldButton);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Please use the "edit" link, not comments, to improve/add to the question

Comment: There's no need to add a `b` tag around it, just change the element's style: `document.getElementById('boldtext').classList.add("bold")` (assuming you have a class called `bold` in your CSS like `.bold { font-weight: bold; }` or similar). Or `document.getElementById('boldtext').style.fontWeight = "bold";` but changing inline styles like that is generally not best practice.

Comment: Please read the documentation. [`+`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition), [`=`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment), [`+=`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment), [`bold`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold).

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
document.getElementById('boldtext').style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
function makeMeBold() {
        document.getElementById('boldtext').style.fontWeight = "bold";
   }
```

```html
<input id="makeBold" type="button" onclick="makeMeBold()" value="Click me"/>
<div id="boldtext">Sample text to make bold</div>
```